# A program tester can not read the print method

Tags: java

I have to write a method that prints values ​​in a matrix using recursion.
When I try to compile the tester I get an error message:"cannot find symbol - method printMat(int[][])".

my Code:

```
public static void printMat(int ma[][]){
    printMat(ma,0,0);   
}

public static void printMat(int m[][], int i, int j){
    System.out.print("[" + m[i][j] + "]");
    if (i == m.length && j == m.length)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (j == m.length)
    {
        j = 0;
        ++i;
        printMat(m, i, j);
    }
    else 
    {
        j++;
        printMat(m, i, j);
    }
}
```

what am doing wrong?

Comment: May you please show where in your code you are calling the method `printMat`?

Comment: it needs to be added where you do method call

Answer (score 0):

In java you define array parameters like so:

```
method(int[][] arr)
```

I'd recommend you reading java documentations and doing some basics tutorials first.

Comment: `int arr[][]` works as well in Java, it is just considered bad form, so that cannot be the problem of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Where is the main method/ root method declared use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}



public static void printMat(int ma[][]) {
            printMat(ma, 0, 0);
        }

        public static void printMat(int m[][], int i, int j) {
            System.out.print("[" + m[i][j] + "]");
            if (i == m.length && j == m.length) {
                return;
            }

            if (j == m.length) {
                j = 0;
                ++i;
                printMat(m, i, j);
            } else {
                j++;
                printMat(m, i, j);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to show here?

Comment: im sorry  but it still does not work

Comment: Im try to show matrix of number that the tester give